# How can I pass data from .js to .vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

I am trying to load data into my .vue component file from its parent .js file.

This is my .html file:

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <section class="modal">
        <modal-component></modal-component>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is my .js file:

```
var modal = new Vue({
    el: 'section.modal',
    data: {
        msg: 'Hello world!'
    },
    components: {
        'modal-component': httpVueLoader('./templates/test.vue')
    }
});
```

This is my .vue file:

```
<template>
    <section>               
        <p class="test">{{ msg }}</p>
    </section>
</template>
```

However, when I load the page, this error appears in the console and the value of 'msg' is blank:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Comment: You either need to define `msg` in `modal-component`'s js file or add a prop for model-component and bind msg to it. Javascript file of model-component is missing in your question.

Comment: Missing the code: under `</template>` add `<script> export default { data: () => {
    return {
      msg: "my message"
    };
  } } </script>`

Answer (score 1):

There are two different Vue instances in play here. The one you create directly using `new Vue` has a property called `msg`. The instance corresponding to the child component, `modal-component`, does not.

There are 3 main types of properties in Vue. `data`, `computed` and `props`.

If you have a property defined on the parent in `data` then you can pass it down to the child using a prop.

```html
<modal-component :msg="msg"></modal-component>
```

In your `.vue` file you would then need to define `msg` as a prop.

```js
props: ['msg']
```

Properties are not automatically inherited, you always need to pass them down using props.

Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Without wishing to muddy the waters, this particular example might be better served using a `slot` but as it's just an example it's difficult to say for sure whether that would really be appropriate.

**Update:**

In full the file `test.vue` would be:

```html
<template>
    <section>               
        <p class="test">{{ msg }}</p>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'modal-component',
  props: ['msg']
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried what you suggested — passing the properly down to the child using a prop — and it the value of msg ('Hello world!') is now attached to the section element, like so: `<section class="modal"><section msg="Hello world!"><p></p></section></section>`. However, my p tag is still empty. How would I display the msg data within the p tag?

Comment: It looks like you haven't declared the prop on the child. If a prop isn't declared it will just be treated as an attribute on the element instead. You need a suitable `<script>` section in your Vue file including `props: ['msg']`.

Comment: I'm so sorry - I don't follow, I'm a little confused! Would it be possible to see an example of what you mean?

Comment: @JamesAnderson Updated. I suggest you have a read of https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html. It's also unclear from your question why you're using `httpVueLoader`, though that doesn't change my answer. If you're new to Vue then I highly recommend grabbing a copy of the CLI tool and automatically generating a skeleton project.